# How do I properly escape weird characters in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting, find, special-characters

I am no professional in scripting or find commands what so ever (Just a warning). 
I am trying to create a script that can move all my mp3 podcasts to a folder that I can then move to my phone.

So the script I made needs to move all mp3's (even those with weird paths). I created a script as follows and it seems* to do what I intended it to but it keeps giving errors as follows:

```
find /home/jason/gPodder/ -name '*.mp3' -exec bash " cp '{}' /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/ " \;
Which returns:    
bash:  cp '/home/jason/gPodder/Downloads/The Documentary/TheDocumentary20170823-GoingGreenInTheOilState.mp3' /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/ : No such file or directory
```

But If I copy the above bash 'command' it works no problem.
Please could you help me understand what my error is in the script.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [@Kusalananda said](/a/389058), you're  missing a `-c` to be able to use an inline-script.

But even then, never embed the `{}` in the shell code, that would be an arbitrary command injection vulnerability (think for instance of a file called `'$(reboot)'.mp3` with your example). Instead make it an argument of the inline script (assuming you do need an inline script here and that the `cp` is just an example).

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" /home/jason/gPodder/mp3' sh {} \;
```

(you also don't need `bash` just for that. Your `sh` will do just as well).

Or even better, pass several arguments at once to `cp`:

```
find ... -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" /home/jason/gPodder/mp3' sh {} +
```

With GNU `cp`, you can also make it:

```
find ... -exec cp -t /home/jason/gPodder/mp3 {} +
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
find /home/jason/gPodder/ -name '*.mp3' -exec cp {} /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/ \;
```

or possibly

```
find /home/jason/gPodder/ -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec cp {} /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/ \;
```

to only consider regular files.

To only copy the file if no file with the same name already exist in the destination folder, some `cp` implementations support a `-n` option for that, or you could use `-i` with stdin redirected from `/dev/null` (but beware those don't work if the target is of type directory) or do something like:

```
find /home/jason/gPodder/ -type f -name '*.mp3' \
    ! -execdir test -e /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/{} \; \
    -exec cp {} /home/jason/gPodder/mp3/ \;
```

`-execdir` is an extension to the POSIX standard `find`, but is supported by many modern `find` implementations. It performs like `-exec` but executes the command with the parent directory of the found thing as its working directory. Also, `{}` will be the basename of the found thing (either `file.mp3` or `./file.mp3` depending on the `find` implementation) rather than the complete path of it. See `man find`.

---

The error stems from `bash "somecommand"`.  When invoking `bash` in this way, `bash` expects `somecommand` to be the path to a script file, not a series of shell commands, and it can't find a script with the name you're giving it.

To execute an arbitrary series of shell commands, you need `bash -c "somecommand"`.

But, in this case, just use `-exec cp` as above or as in [Stéphane Chazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389059/116858).

Comment: Is this save without excluding the `mp3` folder itself?

Comment: @Philippos If a file already exists in the `mp3` subfolder, it will be overwritten with a copy of the found file (which may be the file itself). If this is a concern or not, I don't know.

Comment: @Philippos I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the quoting & execution problems.

I'm going to suggest you don't use find -exec, but instead, find a list of files, and pipe that list to xargs and cp instead. Using the print0 option will help you get round any "funny" characters in file and directory names

e.g.

```
find sourcepath -name \*.mp3 -print0 \
    | xargs -0 cp -t destinationpath
```

The benefit of this is that xargs will collect several filenames together from find and hand them off to cp at the same time so each cp instance may copy 20 or 100 files rather than kicking off 1 cp invocation for each file.
xargs will look after fitting enough file names into the cp command line for you.

You can also add the -P n option to xargs and it'll kick off several cp processes in parallel.

On the basis that your files are on the same file system as the destination mp3 folder. You could add -l to cp and it'll hard link the files into the destination, instead of copying them.

e.g.

```
find sourcepath -name \*.mp3 -print0 \
    | xargs -0 -P 5 \
    cp -l -t destinationpath
```

Comment: Why bother with `xargs`? `find … -exec … +` does the same thing. This isn't the 20th century anymore, today `-exec … +` is supported pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Latency, performance.

Comment: What latency and performance benefits does `xargs` have over `-exec +`?